# Iterate over array of object to build a div structure

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I am trying to create a  structure like the image bellow with angular ng-repeat these data inside Reports array. I know I must use some kind of iteration to achieve it but I am very lost.

[image]

```
$scope.Reports = 
 [
 { Id: 1, Name: 'Report One', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 2, Name: 'Report Core', Year: 2016, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 3, Name: 'Report Alpha', Year: 2016, Month: 3 },
 { Id: 4, Name: 'Report Moon', Year: 2015, Month: 5 },
 { Id: 5, Name: 'Report Sky', Year: 2015, Month: 2 }
 ];
```

I am not sure if I will need to create another arrays to store some data.
Something like this

```
$scope.years = [];
$scope.months = [];
```

Any help will be kindly appreciate it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think You can do it using [angular.filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter) module

```
<ul ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports | groupBy: 'Year'">
  {{ key }}
  <ul ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value | groupBy: 'Month'">
    O{{key1}} 
  <li ng-repeat="p in value1">
    {{p.Name }} 
  </li>
</ul>
</ul>
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/qagucenemo/edit?html,js,output)
Hope it will Help

Comment: It works fine, its exactly was I was looking for, just one thing, is it possible to group them by descending order

Comment: This solution requires a angular.filter module.Can we achieve this without adding filter module ?

Answer (score 1):

May be this will give you some idea -

```
<tr ng-repeat="(key, value) in Reports">
  <td> {{key}} </td> <td> {{ value }} </td>
</tr>
```

Let me know if it works or not

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you can find a way to group by your reports based on date from Controller.
[Here is the code pen](http://codepen.io/Rishii/pen/VazNWq)

```
$scope.getReportGroup = function() {
var groupedReports = {};
angular.forEach($scope.Reports, function(obj, i) {
  if (!groupedReports.hasOwnProperty(obj.Year)) {
    groupedReports[obj.Year + ''] = [];
  }
  groupedReports[obj.Year + ''].push(obj);
});
return groupedReports;
}
```